# Converting ASP.NET 'Web Site' Project to 'Web Application Project', where the project uses Profile heavilly

Tags: asp.net, profile, vs-web-application-project

Here's a project to test anyone's sanity. At my company, my team maintains an ASP.net web-site project that makes heavy use of the Profile object on several pages. Maintainability of the site is at issue since we can't use web.config transformations to separate our test settings from our production settings, and I'd like to use transformations to help implement better practices in general.

One major roadblock to this is the use of the Profile object on most pages, since web application projects do not generate the ProfileCommon class. I've come up with a solution to access profile information, but I question its maintainability - I've modified the pages to inherit from a base class that has a member that implements my 'Profile' object. This makes the Profile object accessible where it is needed, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to go about this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) supports Profile. It is a updated version of Legacy Membership Provider.

However, you will need to rename those tables.

- aspnet_Applications => Applications
- aspnet_Membership => Memberships
- aspnet_Profile => Profiles
- aspnet_Roles => Roles
- aspnet_Users => Users
- aspnet_UsersInRoles => UsersInRoles

Since ASP.NET Universal Providers uses **Entity Framework Code First**, you do not need Store Procedures and other tables.